# AngularJS file upload Firebase Blob Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire, ng-file-upload

Morning, guys.

My question is the following:
I am implementing a patient registration and when a patient clic an image, the system allows him/her to upload a picture of themselves; the image shows itself and finally, when they put all their information, the form is supposed to store the info in the Firebase Storage but, when it happens, browser throws this error **(I am using ng-file-upload for this)**:

> t {t: "storage/invalid-argument", e: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected string.", n: null, r: "FirebaseError"}

and here is my code:

```
<div class="login-overlay" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div class="logo">
        Nourish<br> <span class="smaller">Intelligent Nutrition</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container shadow">
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="header">Registro Paciente</div><br>
            <label for="image">
                <input id="image" type="file" ngf-select="selectFile($files)" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" style="display:none;"/>
                <img ng-src="{{ fileList.name }}" class="userPhoto" err-src="{{ defaultAvatar }}" ng-hide="fileLoad"/>
                <div ng-repeat="file in fileList">
                    <img ngf-src="file" class="userPhoto" err-src="{{ defaultAvatar }}">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs" layout-padding>
            <form name="registerForm">
                <div layout="row">
                    <md-input-container class="md-icon-float" flex="50">
                        <label>Nombre(s)</label>
                        <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/reg/user.svg"></md-icon>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/">
                        <div ng-show="loginForm.firstName.$dirty && loginForm.firstName.$invalid" ng-messages="loginForm.firstName.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                            <div ng-message="pattern">Input must only contain letters</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container flex="50">
                        <label>Apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/">
                        <div ng-show="loginForm.lastName.$dirty && loginForm.lastName.$invalid" ng-messages="loginForm.lastName.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                            <div ng-message="pattern">Input must only contain letters</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div layout="row">
                    <md-input-container flex="40">
                        <label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Fecha..."></md-datepicker> 
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container md-no-float flex="60">
                        <input type="text" name="age" aria-label="calculateAgewMonths(myDate)" ng-value="calculateAgewMonths(myDate)" disabled>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div layout="row">
                    <md-input-container flex="40" class="md-icon-float md-block">
                        <label>Género</label>
                        <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/reg/gender.svg"></md-icon>
                        <md-select name="gender" ng-model="user.gender">
                            <md-option value="femenino">Femenino</md-option>
                            <md-option value="masculino">Masculino</md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container flex="60" class="md-icon-float md-block">
                        <label>Ocupación</label>
                        <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/reg/occupation.svg"></md-icon>
                        <input type="text" name="occupation" ng-model="user.occupation">
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/reg/phone.svg"></md-icon>
                    <input type="tel" md-maxlength="10" name="phone" ng-model="user.phone" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" >
                    <div ng-messages="loginForm.phone.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        <div ng-message="pattern">Sólo puedes introducir números.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
                    <label>Correo Electrónico</label>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/email.svg"></md-icon>
                    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
                    <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        <div ng-message="email">Introduce un correo electrónico válido</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="app/images/pass.svg"></md-icon>
                    <input ng-minlength="4" md-maxlength="10" type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required>
                    <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error">
                        <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        <div ng-message="minlength">La contraseña debe tener más de tres caracteres.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="!registerForm.$valid" ng-click="register(file)">&nbsp Registrar &nbsp</mdbutton>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebaseStorage', 
function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseStorage) {

// Initializate Firebase Authentication
var auth = $firebaseAuth();

// Default Image for user avatar        
$scope.defaultAvatar = 'app/images/account-circle.svg';
$scope.fileLoad = null;

// Define variable to store date
$scope.myDate = new Date();

// Function to calculate Age & months
$scope.calculateAgewMonths = function calculateAgewMonths(bd) {
    // Calculate Years
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - bd.getTime();
    var ageDate  = new Date(ageDifMs);
    var age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

    // Calculate Months
    var months = new Date().getMonth() - $scope.myDate.getMonth();

    return "Edad: " + age + " años con " + months + " meses.";
};

// Function to calculate Age in years
$scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(bd) {
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - bd.getTime();
    var ageDate  = new Date(ageDifMs);
    var age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

    return age;
}

$scope.selectFile = function(file) {
    $scope.fileList = file;
    console.log($scope.fileList);
    $scope.fileLoad = true;
};

$scope.login = function() {
    auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            console.log("Signed in as: ", firebaseUser.uid);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
        });
};

$scope.register = function(file) {
    auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            userID = firebaseUser.uid;

            // Reference for Storage
            var strRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePhotos/' + userID);
            var storage = $firebaseStorage(strRef);

            var uploadTask = storage.$putString(file);

            // Reference for Database
            var db = firebase.database();
            var patientRef = db.ref('patients').child(userID);

            patientRef.set({
                firstName : $scope.user.firstName,
                lastName  : $scope.user.lastName,
                birthday  : $scope.myDate,
                age       : $scope.calculateAge($scope.myDate),
                gender    : $scope.user.gender,
                email     : $scope.user.email,
                occupation: $scope.user.occupation,
                phone     : $scope.user.phone
            })
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
};
```

Hope you can help me to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance, you all! Have a great day!

Comment: if you are using $putstring then you have to use Base64 string or data uri string as the input , hence you need to convert the `file` to base64 or you can use `put` method to upload the file as a BLOB. check `console.log($scope.fileList);` if it's already in blob format

Comment: Hey, @Niladri .. thanks for your response! I got this in the $scope.fileList
"File {$$hashKey: "object:7", $ngfBlobUrl: "blob:http://localhost/dba72842-08d4-4530-872b-b1dbf853b78a". So, I am guessing is in the BLOB format.

Comment: have you tried using `storage.put()` method?

Comment: @Niladri I tried with this: 
var strRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePhotos/' + userID);
//var storage = $firebaseStorage(strRef);
var uploadTask = strRef.put(file); // and the error was the same: "Invalid argument. Expected Blob or File.